# How to make clickable part of a textview in custom list view to open new activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, clickable

I have a custom listview with lazyadapter. I'm trying to make clickable part of the text view on the listview to open a new activity. But I'm stucked.

This is in LazyAdapter (I want to say that this is not an Activity. It is just LazyAdapter class):

```
private Activity activity;
private String[] urls;
private String[] tweets;
private String[] names;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] u, String[] n, String[] t) {
    activity = a;
    urls = u;
    names = n;
    tweets = t;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return urls.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView user = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textUser);
    TextView tweet = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textTweet);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    user.setText(names[position]);

    String[] checkHashtag= tweets[position].split(" ");


    SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();


    for(final String item: checkHashtag){
        if(item.substring(0,1).matches("#")){
            sb.append(item+" ");

            sb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(null, TweetActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("item", item);
                    Intent.startActivity(intent);

                }
            }, sb.length()-item.length(), sb.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        } else sb.append(item+" ");

    }
    tweet.setText(sb);






    if (tweets[position].toLowerCase().contains("http://")
            || tweets[position].toLowerCase().contains("https://")) {

        String[] parts = tweets[position].split(" ");
        for (String item : parts) {
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(item);
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(url.toString());
                Linkify.addLinks(tweet, pattern, "http://");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }




    imageLoader.DisplayImage(urls[position], image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

This is how I called LazyAdapter in Tweet Activity:

```
    LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, pic_urls, user_names, tweets);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

But it is not working. Some problem in startActivity(intent) part.

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent(null, TweetActivity.class);

Here replace `null` by `a`

You must provide activity reference while starting another activity.

Comment: It is not the solution. I can not write there anything but "null".

Answer (score 0):

Write `a.this` instead of `null` in

```
Intnet intent = new Intent(null, TweetActivity.class);
```